# Buddypress Server requirement for 5000 members

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, buddypress

I am working on a project based on buddypress which will act as alumni site. 
Approx No of members # 5000
Any day active members # 1000 max

I am in need of help from community choose the right server requirements

I have chosen currently Godaddy economic plan with 100GB space,unlimited bandwidth and shared hosting.Link: http://in.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx?ci=76393

Will it be sufficient ?

I would appreciate your help .

Thanks and Regards,
Pavan

Comment: This might be better on http://serverfault.com/ or http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the developer of a BuddyPress with 5000 members, you can see in [www.autonautas.com](http://www.autonautas.com/).

I was using a shared hosting in BlueHost, but I migrated to a VPS, because of some performance issues. BussyPress is different than WordPress, specially because cache plugins aren't useful.

For instance, in my case, I need to do some fine-tuning, like configuration in MySQL settings. This configuration are not enabled in a shared hosting, but yes in a VPS. Of course you can begin with a cheaper plan an then migrate. I did that, not in Godaddy, in blue host.

If you need more help, contact me or ask here. I was working a lot with BuddyPress problems!